# Angular 5 Component Selector in variable returning string instead of component content

Tags: javascript, angular

I have some data that contains the selector of a component:

```
{
  label: 'This is a label',
  componentSelector: '<app-mycomponent></app-mycomponent>'
}
```

In my app.component.html

Instead of doing this (for example):

```
<div>
  <app-mycomponent></app-mycomponent>
</div>
```

I would like to do this:

```
{{data.componentSelector}}
```

At the moment when I try this it's returning a string instead of replacing it with the contents of the component.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you try `<div [innerHtml]="data.componentSelector"></div>`?

Comment: No, is just displayed as a string too

Answer (score 1):

You cannot interpolate a component, because it is made up of typescript, html, and css. it has to compile to be displayed, if you think about it, it makes sense.

On another note, even if you could interpolate, it would be a poor Angular Pattern, and could have unexpected outcomes especially in production. Stick to the best practices.